# Include the I18n helpers in Rspec Tests for Services

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-i18n

I'm making use of [Services](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/keeping-your-rails-controllers-dry-with-services) in my app, which is not one of the "standard" app components.

Let's say I have a spec test as follows

require "rails_helper"

```
# spec/services/create_user.rb
RSpec.describe CreateUser, type: :service do
  it "returns the error message" do
    error_message = Foo.new.errors
    expect(error_message).to eq(t("foo.errors.message"))
  end
```

end

Just testing that the string returned matches a specific translation string.

However this throws an error because the helper `t()` isn't available.

I could refer it to explicitly as `I18n.t()`, but for my own curiosity, how do I include the correct module to have the luxury of calling the shorthand form?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to add it to the RSpec configuration using;

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include AbstractController::Translation
end
```

Which means you can then just use `t()` instead of `I18n.t()`

Comment: How to use above outside `it` or `describe` blocks?